# How to re-init tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using the jquery tablesorter plugin. I start off by having a table with values and then I initialise my table like so..

```
$("#myStoreStatusTbl").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[3,1],[10,0],[0,0]],
    stripingRowClass: ['even','odd'],
    stripeRowsOnStartUp: true,
    widthFixed: false, 
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    dateFormat: "uk",
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: 'digit' }, 
        2: { sorter: false }, 
        7: { sorter: false }
    }   
});
```

I later wipe out the contents of a table after an ajax call...

```
$('#myStoreStatusTbl tbody').html('');
```

And then re-populate it with values after an ajax call.

The re-populate is working but all the properties I have applied in the tablesorter init are no longer applied.

I tried to trigger an update after the ajax call...

```
$("#myStoreStatusTbl").trigger("update");
```

But that does not work. Can someone please give me some advice on this?

thanks

Comment: What version of tablesorter are you using? I do not recognize the `stripingRowClass` and `stripeRowsOnStartUp` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try following sequence after the ajax call:

```
$("#myStoreStatusTbl").trigger("update");
var sorting = [[3,1],[10,0],[0,0]]; 
// sort on the list 
$("#myStoreStatusTbl").trigger("sorton",[sorting]);
```

This will execute `sorton` event on newly populated data

Comment: thanks. That worked. It not only re-did the sorting but it also re did the zebra rows and everything that i asked for in the initialisation. Is what you specified above documented anywhere on the tablesorter website?

Comment: Oh..that's really good. Even I haven't found it in any specific documentation but it's mentioned in one of demo example related to appending additional rows via Ajax. Sorry I don't remember the exact Url though.